# PHP Trivia Game using sessions

Tags: php, session

I am creating a trivia game, how it works:

A person goes to the index page.

The system generates him a random question out of the array.
The user answers the questions

If question is right, system will echo 'Correct answer' and will generate a new question.
If question is not equal to answer in the array, system will echo 'Wrong answer' and will generate a new question.

I have done the part of question generations, but I am having problems with the matching answers - Considering if you answer a question, after you click submit, the question automatically changes so your answer will be incorrect unless the randomQuestion stays the same.

My friend told me I need to use sessions for the random questions part, but nothing else.
I am not really sure how would I do this, I am really lost.

This is my code:
Question generation

```
    <?php
session_start();

$questions = array(array('What is Google?', 'god'),
                    array('What is God?', 'gode'),
                    array('Why is god?', 'godee'));


$randomQuestion = array_rand($questions);

$question1 = $questions[0][0];
$question2 = $questions[1][0];
$question3 = $questions[2][0];

if ($randomQuestion == 0 && !isset($_SESSION['question1'])) {
    echo $question1;

} else if ($randomQuestion == 1 && !isset($_SESSION['question2'])) {
    echo $question2;

} else if ($randomQuestion == 2 && !isset($_SESSION['question3'])) {
    echo $question3;

}
?>
```

Form + matching answers
This script is currently only checking for question 1 as a test.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Answer it!">
</form>

<?php
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    if (!empty($answer)) {
        if ($randomQuestion == 0) {
            if ($answer == $questions[0][1]) {
                echo 'Correct Answer!';
                unset($_SESSION['question1']);
                unset($_SESSION['question2']);
                unset($_SESSION['question3']);
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Answer is incorrect.';
            return;
        }
    } else {
    echo 'Field is empty';
    return;
    }
session_destroy();
?>
```

What I have thought of:

After reading much articles about sessions, I thought about checking if randomQuestion is isset, if it's isset, then it won't generate new questions.

After you answer the question, it will unset the random question so the system can generate a new question.

But it didn't really work as I didn't do it right.

What did I do wrong?
And what is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't start by using sessions. Of course I may end up using them but for a proof of concept it's best to do it the simple way first.

All you really need to do is insert a hidden value into your form that will tell you the question number.

For example (not tested):

```
<?php

$questions = array(
    array('What is Google?', 'god'),
    array('What is God?', 'gode'),
    array('Why is god?', 'godee')
);


$rnd=mt_rand(0,count($questions)-1);
$question=$questions[$rnd];

echo($question[0]);

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="<?=$rnd?>">
<input type="text" name="answer">
<input type="submit" value="Answer it!">
</form>
```

The rest of the server code to verify the question and answer I'll leave as an exercise.

Comment: Just got to test this out, and still same problem - question is being changed after clicking submit button, and then the answer won't match it.

Comment: Did you put the form checking coding at the top of the php file? I've also changed the name of the variable to 'q' so as to not conflict with the '$question' variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this trivia game to be played by more that one person (and I suppose you do) , you need to come up with something more that a simple < form > ... You must store the answers one user gives so that the other user can see them.